# Why store all reference ids?

Tags: mongodb

lets say I have one to many relation with `Post` and `Comment` models.

When embedding is not used he suggested way to handle data relation is:

```
const PostSchema = new Schema({
  _id: Types.ObjectId,
  comments: [{type: Types.ObjectId, ref:'comment'}]
})

const CommentSchema = new Schema({
  _id:Types.ObjectId
})
```

Wouldnt the schema design below be more appropriate?(storing `postId` as foreign key in `Comment`). And also is there a name for such relation method?

```
const PostSchema = new Schema({
  _id: Types.ObjectId
})

const CommentSchema = new Schema({
  _id:Types.ObjectId,
  postId: Types.ObjectId
})
```

To get a post and all its comments I would simply do:

```
let post = await Post.find({ _id: postId });
post.comments = await Comment.find({ postId });
```

With the first method, every time a new comment is created, the post document must be updated as well. And if we want to guarantee that commentId is added to `comments` array, we should use transaction, which makes this update even more costly.

However with the second approach, we only have to create comment.
Now the downside is that I will not be able to use `$lookup`, but performance wise, would it make much of a difference? `$lookup` is not like `JOIN` in relational databases, where `JOIN`s are done in a single database operation. So using `$lookup` or simply querying by comment's `postId`(indexed) to "JOIN" the data would not make much of a difference in terms of performance.

Comment: https://coderwall.com/p/px3c7g/mongodb-schema-design-embedded-vs-references this could clear your confusions

Comment: and this https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/data-models/

Comment: i would use the first one. if you want to go this relational way why dont you use mysql for example?

Comment: @Naresh You have misunderstood my question. I am not asking when to embed or reference the subdocuments.

Comment: @Ifaruki I think thats a trivial question. There is nothing wrong to have relations in mongodb. You cannot embed everything in a single document. Anyway, my question is not about when to embed or not.

Comment: there will always be a trade-off between those two approaches. If the number of get requests to get comments will be higher then you should go with the first approach but if the number of requests to add comments will be greater you should go with the second approach.  and weren't you asking which approach woulld be better performance wise?

Comment: @Naresh both methods are "not-embedding", they are both referencing comments. I am asking which way of referencing is better. In first method, `comments` field is not nested `comments`. They are nested `ids`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your example can be found [in the documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-referenced-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/) applied to a different domain model (comments are books and posts are publishers).

> When using references, the growth of the relationships determine where to store the reference. If the number of comments per post is small with limited growth, storing the comment reference inside the post document may sometimes be useful. Otherwise, if the number of comments per post is unbounded, this data model would lead to mutable, growing arrays...

> To avoid mutable, growing arrays, store the post reference inside the comment document

The document schema should be oriented on your use case requirements, which define your queries. As you identified, it makes sense to store the post reference on the comment, so you don't have to update the post every time you create a new comment. So without more information about growth rates, access frequency and other loading scenarios it sounds like option 2 makes more sense in this context.

Answer (score 0):

The first approach is unusual but it can work in some situations depending on query needs.